# How to expand a variable that contains a mixture of text and other variables?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, environment-variables, variable-expansion

I am writing an script and I need to locate the desktop folder of the current user. I want it to be language-independent so I found that on Ubuntu you can find the path of the desktop (independently of the system language) in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` in the line beginning with the tag `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR`.

I can capture this information easily using `DESK=$(more ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs | grep "XDG_DESKTOP_DIR" | cut -d '"' -f2)` and obtain the path of the Desktop, but the problem is that I obtain something like this: `$HOME/Desktop` and I need to expand the $HOME variable.

I was doing it with `eval` but I know that is bad coding so I decided to change it.

So basically I am trying to expand the variable that is inside a variable that contains a mixture of text and variables. I would like to have a solution for this that is not hardcoded for the `$HOME` variable, because this is not the first time that I find this issue.

I already tried `${!DESK}`, `${${DESK}}` (I can imagine why this is not working), `[[ ${escri} ]]` and others in combination with `echo -e`.

I would be super grateful if someone can help me with this issue since I remember that I already had this problem the first time that I wrote the code, that's why I gave up and used the wicked `eval`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most useful way is to source `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

```sh
. ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

# Variable is now readily available
echo "$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR"
```

Another way is to use `envsubst` to expand the environment variables before parsing the file:

```sh
desktop_dir="$(
  envsubst < ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs |
   sed -n 's/XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="\(.*\)"/\1/p'
)"
```

Comment: Another useful use of `envsubst` up voted. learned something from this.